# Can't run a simple Prolog program

Tags: prolog, logic

I'm trying to find out what will be the output of this program:

```
p(X):-p(Y). p(a). p(b). p(c). and goal ?-p(Z)
```

So I've tried to put into online interpreter:

```
p(X):-p(Y). p(a). p(b). p(c).
?-p(Z).
```

But nothing happend. Where is the problem?

I'm very new to Prolog.

Comment: Your predicate p has infinite recursion : `p(X) :- p(Y).` says that `p` is true for a variable `X` if `p` is true for a variable Y. Therefore it will check `p(Y)` on the same rule, which will be true if `p` is true for another variable, etc. and it will never stop. That's why you don't see anything, the interpreter is evaluating an infinite query, and it won't even produce a stack overflow because it will be optimized in this case since it is tail-recursive.

Comment: @Fatalize Thanks, so I tried this: p(X) :- q(Y). q(X) :- p(Y). p(a). p(b). p(c). and a goal ?- p(Z). And it is the same. Should it be looping too?

Comment: Well yes it should. Now you're saying that `p` is true for a variable if `q` is true for an other variable, and that `q` is true for a variable  if `p` is true for an other variable. There's still no end to that recursion. Overall I don't understand what you're trying to accomplish here.

Comment: you don't need a rule for `p(X)` at ll. Just having those three facts is enough. when you'll ask `p(Z)`, it will go through the three of them, one at a time, on itself. No need to define a rule for that to happen.